# WebAPI Controller Methods that Differ By Value Types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing API I'm moving over to WebAPI, so I'm not free to change the URL. Breaking existing clients is not an option for me.

Knowing that, the original API would accept either a Guid (an ID) or a string (a name) for a given action method. The old API handler would decipher the URL parameter and send the request to a controller action designed to accept the given parameter type.

As an example:

```
Get(Guid id)
```

versus

```
Get(string name)
```

With WebAPI, the parameter binding is greedy across value types, so depending on which is first in the controller source file, that action is the one invoked. For my needs, that's not working. I was hoping the binder would realize the conversion to a Guid would fail for a name and then select the more generic string-based action. No dice. The Guid simply comes across as a null value (interestingly since it's a value type, but that's what I'm getting in the debugger at a certain point in the processing).

So my question is how best to handle this? Do I need to go as far as implementing a custom IHttpActionSelector? I tried the attribute routing approach (with constraints), but that isn't working quite right (bummer as it looks cool). Is there a mechanism in WebAPI that accounts for this I don't (yet) know about? (I know I can hack it in by testing the string for Guid-ness and invoking the other controller method, but I'm hoping for a more elegant, WebAPI-based solution...)

Comment: `Guid` turning up `null`? Sounds fishy to me. `string` is not a value type. How are you posting this data?

Comment: It's actually turning up null in an attribute I wrote to handle ETags that's in the pipeline. The attribute looks into the route action arguments for the named parameter and doesn't find it. (You're right in that a Guid can't actually be null...I just didn't give you all the details.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd spent a lot of time trying to fit attribute-based routing in, but I've not got that to work. However, I did solve my particular issue using route constraints. If you register the more-constrained route first, WebAPI (like MVC) will apply the constraints and skip over more-constrained routes until it finds one that it can select, if any.

So, using my example, I'd set up routes like so:

```
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ById",
    routeTemplate: "product/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ProductDetails" },
    constraints: new { id = @"^\{?[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}\}?$" });
_config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ByName",
    routeTemplate: "product/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ProductDetails" });
```

The first route accepts a constraint in the form of a regular expression for a Guid. The second accepts all other values, and the controller will deal with non-product names (returns a 404). I tested this in the self-hosted WebAPI server and it works fantastically.

I am sure attribute-based routing would be more elegant, but until I get that to work, it's routing the old way for me. At least I found a reasonable WebAPI-based solution.